# How Can I Keep the Footer Below My Picture Gallery

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I already figured out how to keep the footer at the bottom of the other pages of the website I am trying to develop. But I can't figure out how to do it on my page with a photo gallery. The footer stays in the middle of the page. :(

Here is my HTML code for that page:

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  color: #FF6347;
  font-family: 'Ceviche One', cursive;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  position:relative;
}
#footer {
  background-color: #E9967A;
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
#gallery {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#gallery li {
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  width: 45%;
  margin: 2.5%;
  background-color: #FFEBCD;
  color: #FF6347;
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <p class="sectionheader">Beautiful Places in Tyria</p>
        <ul id="gallery">
           <li><p class="captionheader">Garden of Dawn</p>
           <a href="img/treehouse Garden of Dawn.jpg">
             <img src="img/treehouse Garden of Dawn.jpg" alt="">
           </a>
           </li>
           <li><p class="captionheader">The Planetarium</p>
           <a href="img/treehouse The Planetarium.jpg">
             <img src="img/treehouse The Planetarium.jpg" alt="">
           </a>
           </li>
           <li><p class="captionheader">Wizard's Fief</p>
           <a href="img/treehouse Wizard's Fief.jpg">
             <img src="img/treehouse Wizard's Fief.jpg" alt="">
           </a></li>
           <li><p class="captionheader">Black Citadel Statues</p>
           <a href="img/treehouse Black Citadel Statues.jpg">
             <img src="img/treehouse Black Citadel Statues.jpg" alt="">
           </a></li>
           <li><p class="captionheader">Shrine of the Six</p>
           <a href="img/treehouse Shrine of the Six.jpg">
             <img src="img/treehouse Shrine of the Six.jpg" alt="">
           </a></li>
         </ul>
       <div id="footer">
        <a href="http://facebook.com/rejisama">
          <img src="img/facebook-wrap.png" alt="Facebook logo" class="social-icon">
        </a>
        <a href="http://twitter.com/nogoodreji">
           <img src="img/twitter-wrap.png" alt="Twitter logo" class="social-icon">
        </a>
        <p>&copy; 2016 All rights reserved.</p>
       </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  color: #FF6347;
  font-family: 'Ceviche One', cursive;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.content{
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  }
#wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width:100%;
  display: block;
}
.content{
  display: block;
}
#footer {
  background-color: #E9967A;
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 30px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  display:block;
  
}
#gallery {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width:100%;

}
#gallery li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 2.5%;
  background-color: #FFEBCD;
  color: #FF6347;
  }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <p class="sectionheader">Beautiful Places in Tyria</p>
        <ul id="gallery">
           <li><p class="captionheader">Garden of Dawn</p>
           <a href="img/treehouse Garden of Dawn.jpg">
             <img src="img/treehouse Garden of Dawn.jpg" alt="">
           </a>
           </li>
           <li><p class="captionheader">The Planetarium</p>
           <a href="img/treehouse The Planetarium.jpg">
             <img src="img/treehouse The Planetarium.jpg" alt="">
           </a>
           </li>
           <li><p class="captionheader">Wizard's Fief</p>
           <a href="img/treehouse Wizard's Fief.jpg">
             <img src="img/treehouse Wizard's Fief.jpg" alt="">
           </a></li>
           <li><p class="captionheader">Black Citadel Statues</p>
           <a href="img/treehouse Black Citadel Statues.jpg">
             <img src="img/treehouse Black Citadel Statues.jpg" alt="">
           </a></li>
           <li><p class="captionheader">Shrine of the Six</p>
           <a href="img/treehouse Shrine of the Six.jpg">
             <img src="img/treehouse Shrine of the Six.jpg" alt="">
           </a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
       </div>
       <div id="footer">
        <a href="http://facebook.com/rejisama">
          <img src="img/facebook-wrap.png" alt="Facebook logo" class="social-icon">
        </a>
        <a href="http://twitter.com/nogoodreji">
           <img src="img/twitter-wrap.png" alt="Twitter logo" class="social-icon">
        </a>
        <p>&copy; 2016 All rights reserved.</p>
       </div>
    
   
  </body>
```

Comment: Oh! Great, at the end I saw an Iranian here :)  Nice answer but it is better to add a description too.., btw: I also suggest [CSS tricks post](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)  about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you make the `ul#gallery` have a property of `display:inline-block;` it will give the gallery a physical height (because at the moment my browser says the height is zero) and push the footer to the bottom.